# OpenStack Autopilot VMware testing

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, openstack, cloud

I'm looking to test autopilot, however the installation instructions are a bit minimal and literally odd. For example, the very first instruction is to load the VM into vSphere which as I understand is only available on Windows. I'd much rather just be able to use virtualbox, qemu, kvm etc. Is there any more documentation on this, or is this it?

Marty

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is VM control through Virsh. just continue to install as per the instructions and just write anything in the VMware configuration questions.
afterwards, when you log into MAAS interface, you'll find under each machine's settings the power control types. This includes virsh.

From there you can sert up virsh URL/username/password/etc..

first time though, just to have the VM "nodes" show up in MAAS, you have to power them up yourself and make sure they boot from the PXE interface.